# Nativescript 5 : how to navigate from a root tab component totally and goes to an other one?

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have a project like this one:
a project with this structure:

```
-app.component.ts (root tab)
---home.module
--------home tab (outlet)
--------categories tab (outlet)
--------etc.. (outlet)
---login.module(lazy loaded)
---ex.module (lazy loaded)
```

this is my app-routing module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/home/(homeTab:home//categoriesTab:categories//infoTab:info//locationsTab:locations//accountTab:account)", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "home", loadChildren: "./app/home/home.module#HomeModule" },
  { path: "login", loadChildren: "./app/login/login.module#LoginModule" },
  { path: "ex", loadChildren: "./app/ex/ex.module#ExModule" }
]
```

now I want to leave tab view totally and go to login module which has its own (non-tab) view from "home tab(outlet)".
I tried to navigate using routerExtension with parameter relative to activatedRoute.root but it doesn't work.

here is an example of the issue: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=IyP222&v=11

Comment: You may directly navigate to login, it need not to be relative. If you still face issues, can you recreate the scenario with Playground?

Comment: @Manoj i have updated my question with a playground link .

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the given scenario still has issues to be addressed with latest version of nativescript-angular (v6.2.0). Refer the [Github Issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1351#issuecomment-437379377) where the team has provided working sample using latest @next version.